# How do I specify default values in DAML for primitive types and records?

Tags: daml

I don't see a way to specify a default value in DAML. Say I want to specify False as the default value for a Bool or the time now as the default value for a variable of type Time. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DAML does not provide a way to specify default values. However, you can create functions that set the defaults, e.g., let’s say you have a template T:

```
template T 
  with
    p : Party
    value : Int
  where
    signatory p
```

You can now define a function `createT` that will set `value` to `42`:

```
createT : Party -> T
createT p = T with
  p = p
  value = 42
```

You can then overide the default using `with`-syntax, e.g.

```
(createT alice) with value = 43
```